# Azure Powershell - Deployment Template Validation Failed - Jtoken

Tags: json, azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to deploy multiple virtual machines one at a time with Powershell and a template file but I keep getting this error:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 9:27:40 AM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation
failed: 'Template parameter JToken type is not valid. Expected 'String, Uri'. Actual 'Object'. Please see
https://aka.ms/resource-manager-parameter-files for usage details.'.
At C:\Users\jackk\OneDrive\Desktop\AzureAutomation\main.ps1:193 char:9
+         New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @parameters
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
   loymentCmdlet

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : The deployment validation failed
At C:\Users\jackk\OneDrive\Desktop\AzureAutomation\main.ps1:193 char:9
+         New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @parameters
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzResourceGroupDeployment], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.Implementation.NewAzureResourceGroupDep
   loymentCmdlet
```

Here is the relevant part of my powershell script:

```
$location = "eastus2"
$networkInterfaceName = ""
$networkSecurityGroupName = ""
#$networkSecurityGroupRules = @()
$subnetName = $SubnetSelection
$virtualNetworkId = "/subscriptions/1234-1234-123-123-123/resourceGroups/MainGroup/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/Main_Network"
$virtualMachineName = ""
$virtualMachineComputerName = ""
$virtualMachineRG = $resourceGroupSelection
$osDiskType = "StandardSSD_LRS"
$virtualMachineSize = "Standard_B2s"
$adminUsername = "ADMIN"
$adminPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "Password1234" -AsPlainText -Force
$diagnosticsStorageAccountName = $StorageAccountName
$diagnosticsStorageAccountId = $StorageAccountID
$imageName = $ImageSelection    

foreach ($i in 1..5) {
    
    $virtualMachineName = "test-$i".ToString()
    $virtualMachineComputerName = "test-$i".ToString()
    $rand = Get-Random -Maximum 1000
    $networkInterfaceName = "test-$i$rand".ToString()
    $networkSecurityGroupName = "test-$i-nsg".ToString()

    $paramObject = @{
        'location' = $location
        'networkInterfaceName' = $networkInterfaceName
        'networkSecurityGroupName' = $networkSecurityGroupName
        'subnetName' = $SubnetSelection
        'virtualNetworkId' = $virtualNetworkId
        'virtualMachineName' = $virtualMachineName
        'virtualMachineComputerName' = $virtualMachineComputerName
        'virtualMachineRG' = $resourceGroupSelection
        'osDiskType' = $osDiskType
        'virtualMachineSize' = $virtualMachineSize
        'adminUsername' = $adminUsername
        'adminPassword' = $adminPassword
        'diagnosticsStorageAccountName' = $diagnosticsStorageAccountName
        'diagnosticsStorageAccountId' = $diagnosticsStorageAccountId
        'imageName' = $imageName
    }

    $parameters = @{
        'ResourceGroupName' = $resourceGroupSelection
        'TemplateFile' = $PathTemplate
        'TemplateParameterObject' = $paramObject
        'Verbose' = $True
    }

    New-AzResourceGroupDeployment @parameters

}
```

Assume any variables not defined in this snippet are strings defined elsewhere with valid information.

The Template file I am using:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "networkInterfaceName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
            "type": "Array",
            "defaultValue": []
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworkId": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualMachineComputerName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualMachineRG": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "osDiskType": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualMachineSize": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "type": "SecureString"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountName": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "diagnosticsStorageAccountId": {
            "type": "String"
        },
        "imageName": {
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {
        "nsgId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
        "vnetId": "[parameters('virtualNetworkId')]",
        "subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "ipConfigurations": [
                    {
                        "name": "ipconfig1",
                        "properties": {
                            "subnet": {
                                "id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
                            },
                            "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "networkSecurityGroup": {
                    "id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
            "apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
            "name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "properties": {
                "securityRules": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupRules')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
            "apiVersion": "2019-07-01",
            "name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "hardwareProfile": {
                    "vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
                },
                "storageProfile": {
                    "osDisk": {
                        "createOption": "fromImage",
                        "managedDisk": {
                            "storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
                        }
                    },
                    "imageReference": {
                        "id": "[parameters('imageName')]"
                    }
                },
                "networkProfile": {
                    "networkInterfaces": [
                        {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName'))]"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "osProfile": {
                    "computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineComputerName')]",
                    "adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
                    "adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
                    "windowsConfiguration": {
                        "enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
                        "provisionVmAgent": true
                    }
                },
                "diagnosticsProfile": {
                    "bootDiagnostics": {
                        "enabled": true,
                        "storageUri": "[concat('https://', parameters('diagnosticsStorageAccountName'), '.blob.core.windows.net/')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "adminUsername": {
            "type": "String",
            "value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything I could think of and I think I've narrowed the issue down to `networkSecurityGroupRules`. I took this template file from a valid deployment in Azure and the parameter file that came with `networkSecurityGroupRules` had the value of the that set to `[]`. So I created a default value for it but it does not work. I've also tried declaring it as a empty array in powershell and passing it through with the other paramObjects but I get the same error. I've tried ArrayList as well to no avail. I have also filled in a parameter.json file with the exact values I pass to it in `$paramObjects` and it works flawlessly. If I change the `defaultValue` to null, then on deployment it will ask me to fill in networkSecurityGroupRules[0], networkSecurityGroupRules[1], etc.. I really don't know where the issue is so any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: COuld you please tell me the error message when you use `"defaultValue": []`?

Comment: I get the same exact error message that's shown at the beginning. I decided to completely remove the NSG from the template and I create it manually instead using `New-AzNetworkSecurityGroup`, then I use the template. This was my solution to the problem but I'm still going to keep this up because I'd like to know why what I have above did not work.

Comment: Since you do not want to define rules in your nsg, why you add `securityRules` in your template. It is not required : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.network/networksecuritygroups

Comment: I tried removing it already but then it will prompt me for the rules regardless when running the script in the form: networksecurityrules[0], networksecurityrules[1], etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Everything in the 'paramObject' must be in quotes. For example, `'location' = $location` must be `'location' = "$location"`